# Is there any example for jquery slideshow with zoom in, zoom out effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image slideshow and I want to make a Zoom in, Zoom out effect in that. Now I am using jQuery Cycle plugin. Does anybody have any suggestions on how to do this? Your help would be really appreciated.

Comment: (offtopic... @Bolt... congrats for your diamond!)

Answer (score 0):

Try [these](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/10/jquery-image-zoom.html) out

Comment: @Suresh ... may you describe please the exact effect in details? cause 'zoom in' is a bit vague, knowing that there's tons of examples - ways - to achieve this

Comment: see i want the images are in the slideshow are  zoom In slowly then fadeout like that ok